# Desire2Learn Valence API Course Creation Path Information Incorrect

Tags: php, creation, desire2learn

Im doing some testing with course creation with the php valence api, everything works fine on course creation but the path information isn't correct, for whatever reason it just creates a folder in enforced with the name as the course code. Am I missing something?

```
$rand_course_id =  rand( 99999, 999999);
echo $rand_course_id;
$json = '{
    "Name": "Valence '.$rand_course_id.'",
    "Code": "VALENCE_'.$rand_course_id.'",
    "Path": "/content/enforced ",
    "CourseTemplateId": "6722",
    "SemesterId": null,
    "StartDate": null,
    "EndDate": null,
    "LocaleId": null,
    "ForceLocale": "false",
    "ShowAddressBook": "true"
}';`
mphs_json_request('courses',$json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config variable that forces the paths of course content into a particular form. The variable is d2l.Tools.CMS.CoursePathEnforced. Perhaps this value is on in your system?

Comment: thanks for the tip, our system currently has it on.  So looks like it could be a dead end road for me unless I can get it turned on.